# Swift :: Traverse a json string

Tags: json, string, swift

Here is a string looks like a json.

```
let text2 = " [{ \"insertion_date\" :\""+"2015-07-31 11:21:04 +0000"+"\",\"mood\":  \""+"Happy"+"\",\"temperature\": \""+"22"+"\"},{ \"insertion_date\" :\""+"2015-07-31 11:21:04 +0000"+"\",\"mood\":  \""+"Sad"+"\",\"temperature\": \""+"22"+"\"}]"
```

I can access the whole string like this.

```
var data = text2.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
var localError: NSError?
var json3: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError)
println(json3)
```

But now I want to access individual element of this string, like - I want to access the second "mood" key, which has the value "Sad". 
How can I access it?

Comment: You could try removing the AnyObject declaration and adding `as? NSDicionary` to the end of `json3`. Now you can access like a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
var jsonArr: NSArray! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError) as! NSArray
for dict in jsonArr {
    print(dict.objectForKey("mood"))
}
```

Which will print each of the moods.

Answer (score 0):

Swift's native JSON parsing is a pain due to all the optional unwrapping:

```
if let days = json3 as? NSArray {
    if let secondDay = days[1] as? NSDictionary {
        let mood = secondDay["mood"] as! String
        print(mood)
    }
}
```

You can use other framework like SwiftyJson for an easier time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Swift's native types instead of NSArray and NSDictionary, and cast the result of `NSJSONSerialization` as an array of dictionaries (`[[String:AnyObject]]`):

```
if let json3 = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &localError) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for dict in json3 {
        if let mood = dict["mood"] as? String {
            println(mood)
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that you don't need to give specific options to NSJSONSerialization, you can pass nil in this case.

If you're absolutely certain that your values will always be of type String, you can also cast the result directly (and avoid later casts when accessing values):

```
if let json3 = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &localError) as? [[String:String]] {
    for dict in json3 {
        if let mood = dict["mood"] {
            println(mood)
        }
    }
}
```